# I want to solve my problem with some one

Tags: tense, backshifting

What is the future in the past tense? Which kind of tense is this?
A person asked me what is the difference between lexical tenses and the compound tenses and he said that future in the past is a compound tense and simple present tense is a lexical tense some please help!

Comment: I am not familiar with a distinction between 'lexical' and 'compound' tenses, and the word *tense* itself has many meanings in English grammar. I could guess what you mean; but I think we would all be happier if you edited your question to define these terms and gave examples of just what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English has two morphological tenses, **present** and **past**.  These are forms which are used primarily to locate situations in time, although they have other uses as well:

> I **walk**.　　 ←　*present*
>   I **walked**.　←　*past*

If you're going to call something a "lexical tense", it's probably going to be these two.  So if I were to use this term, I would agree with your friend that the simple present is a "lexical tense".

---

On the other hand, English can also locate situations in time through a variety of constructions.  For example, using a modal auxiliary like ***may***, ***might***, or ***will*** often suggests future time:

> I **may see** that movie.
>   I **might see** that movie.
>   I **will see** that movie.

Although English lacks a morphological future tense, you can certainly express a future time meaning through this sort of construction, given the right context.  If you're going to call something a "compound tense", it's probably going to be the sort of construction I've listed above.

But keep in mind that this term isn't very well defined.  Which constructions should be considered "compound tenses", and which should not?  There are simply too many combinations of auxiliaries and auxiliary-like constructions (*"I **am going to see** that movie"*) to give names to all of them, and it's not clear which of them, if any, should be called "tenses" in the first place.  If we're going to call something a tense, its primary use should be to locate a situation in time.  [But even ***will*** isn't really a future time auxiliary; it's a modal auxiliary, just like ***may*** or ***might***](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=897).

But let's set that aside for a moment.  What about the "future in the past" idea?  Well, there are lots of ways to express that, but you probably have a particular construction in mind.  Maybe something like this:

> I ruined my sister's car!  She **was going to kill** me!

So, sure.  We could call this future-in-the-past construction a "compound tense".  Why?  Because it's got more than one word in it, and it can be used to locate a situation in time.  Just keep in mind that these terms are a bit murky to begin with.  Many linguists describe English without ever using terms like "compound tense".